# jquery cookie check and set

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have some age-restricted content needed to confirm 18 years old stuff. so I made a cookie check if he clicked "yes I am older 18" button. I simple set cookie and next time he visit check the cookie.

so simply I try to part one is "yes button div" other check function and screen block div..
nothing happens 18block div(screen blocker) always shows.

looking for your help fellas :)
thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if ($.cookie('18ekran') != null) {
            $.cookie('18ekran', '18ekran', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
            $("#18ekran").attr('style', 'display:none;');
        }
    });
    $("#evet").click(function () {
        $("#18ekran").attr('style', 'display:none;');
        $.cookie("asucan18", "asucan18", { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you set the style attribute? You can use `.css('property', 'value')` or even easier `.hide()`......

Comment: what is matter? all works right? :)

Comment: You don't use a chainsaw to cut your bread just because it "works right". You also don't use a blowtorch to heat your lunch. Both methods "work", but are not the proper ones.

Comment: If Its make you feel better I used to heat my lunch with iron and I dont cut my bread. pls stay on main topic :) thanks

Comment: Comments **are** a place where you can make suggestions which are related to but not answer the question or parts of it.

Comment: IDs starting with a number are illegal.

Comment: @BalusC changed with ekran18 but same :(

Comment: It wasn't an answer. It was just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was silly problem just changed the order of jquery script and cookie script. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#18ekran").css('display', 'none');
```